# Enumerating simple algebraic groups and their irreducible representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, enumerative-combinatorics

## Motivation

Everything is over an algebraically closed field.

Given a faithful representation $G \to \textrm{GL}(V)$, one may try to pin down what the group $G$ exactly is (e.g., the in the case of the Mumford–Tate group of a Hodge structure). If the dimension of $V$ is known, the list of groups already becomes finite. Sometimes we have even more information (e.g., the level of the Hodge structure).

In the following, let us assume (for simplicity, pun unintended) that we know that $G$ is simple, and the representation is irreducible. So, our problem of pinning down $G$ boils down to finding its Cartan type.

In the end, I am trying to write some Sage code that gives me a list of candidate groups based on this data (e.g., dimension, level).

## Question

> **Q:** Is there an efficient enumeration of the Cartan types, and their dominant weights?
>
> It would be really nice if this enumeration grows more or less with the dimension of the representations.

**Notes:**

- In particular I would like to list the dominant weights as tuples $(m_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$, so that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_{i}\varpi_{i}, m_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}$ is a dominant weight (with $(\varpi_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ the fundamental weights of the particular Cartan type).
- I realise that *efficient* enumeration is a bit vague. I roughly mean that it should not take pages to describe this enumeration, or put it in a computer. Anyway, please drop the *efficient* if it bothers you (-;

### First attempt

My first attempt at an enumeration is as follows:

$N = 1$

- List all tuples $(X_{n}, (m_{i})_{i=1}^{n})$ (where $X_{n}$ is a Cartan type of rank $n$, and $(m_{i})_{i=1}^{n}$ a dominant weight tuple as described above) such that $n + \sum_{i=1}^{n} m_{i} = N$.
- Increase $N$ by $1$, and repeat.

Any tips, hints, critic, &c is very welcome.

> **Q:** Is there anything written about this in the literature?